# tail: unrecognised file system type error while doing tail -f

Tags: ubuntu, command, tail

Why it is showing error while doing -f but not doing --silent and --quite.
what could be the difference. I searched every where but did not find difference?

```
root@<containerID>:/crowdLogistics/client/internal# tail --silent ../../logs/gunicorn_internal_client.log 
[2018-09-06 07:06:30 +0000] [69] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
[2018-09-06 07:06:30 +0000] [69] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (69)
[2018-09-06 07:06:30 +0000] [69] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-09-06 07:06:30 +0000] [74] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 74
[2018-09-06 07:06:30 +0000] [77] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 77
[2018-09-06 07:06:30 +0000] [78] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 78
[2018-09-06 07:06:30 +0000] [81] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 81
[2018-09-06 07:06:30 +0000] [84] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 84

root@<containerID>:/crowdLogistics/client/internal# tail --quiet ../../logs/gunicorn_internal_client.log 
[2018-09-06 07:06:30 +0000] [69] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
[2018-09-06 07:06:30 +0000] [69] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (69)
[2018-09-06 07:06:30 +0000] [69] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-09-06 07:06:30 +0000] [74] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 74
[2018-09-06 07:06:30 +0000] [77] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 77
[2018-09-06 07:06:30 +0000] [78] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 78
[2018-09-06 07:06:30 +0000] [81] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 81
[2018-09-06 07:06:30 +0000] [84] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 84

root@<containerID>:/crowdLogistics/client/internal# tail -f ../../logs/gunicorn_internal_client.log 
[2018-09-06 07:06:30 +0000] [69] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
[2018-09-06 07:06:30 +0000] [69] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (69)
[2018-09-06 07:06:30 +0000] [69] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-09-06 07:06:30 +0000] [74] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 74
[2018-09-06 07:06:30 +0000] [77] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 77
[2018-09-06 07:06:30 +0000] [78] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 78
[2018-09-06 07:06:30 +0000] [81] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 81
[2018-09-06 07:06:30 +0000] [84] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 84
tail: unrecognized file system type 0x794c7630 for ‘../../logs/gunicorn_internal_client.log’. please report this to bug-coreutils@gnu.org. reverting to polling
```

Comment: How is this question related to python? Or to docker? You are just running `tail`.

Comment: Doing tail while working on docker in a python project. it might give some idea that where are you using tail.

Comment: suppose if someone ask, where you using suppress command atleast they should have idea. what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks anyway :) @VonC. I got the solution. But this is too temporary.

follow these instructions on your local docker to get tail command working

```
cd /root
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/coreutils-8.27.tar.xz && tar xf coreutils-8.27.tar.xz
export FORCE_UNSAFE_CONFIGURE=1
cd /root/coreutils-8.27 && ./configure \
--prefix=/root/coreutils \
--libexecdir=/root/coreutils/lib \
--enable-no-install-program=kill,uptime && make && make install

/root/coreutils/bin/tail -f «filename»
```

Answer (score 1):

`root@<containerID>`  means you are in a container session (through `docker exec` for instance)

From there, the `tail -f` warning `unrecognized file system type` can depend on the version of coreutil present in your image. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121202/7490) for illustration.

There has been [patches to coreutils](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=commitdiff;h=v8.25-25-g8c81638) depending on the execution environment.
In your case (execution environment is docker), see [bitnami-docker-tensorflow-serving issue 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20201230164428/https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-tensorflow-serving/issues/2)

It happens when using Docker with the overlay driver: [Bug 810669](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=810669):

> Caused by base image using old version of coreutils which causes "`tail: unrecognized file system type 0x794c7630` for '`/var/log/cron.log`'" when using docker with overlay storage driver.
>
> It might get fixed once we update the base image from Debian Jessie (oldstable) to Debian Stretch (stable)